# How to add sorting on header using angularjs filter?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to add sorting functionality on date header, I added `orderBy` filter but it's breaking the column.

How can I add sorting to date header? I would like for it to be possible for the user to click the header, which should change the sorting order.

**main.html**

```
   <table>
    <tr>
        <th>File</th>
        <th>{{date | orderBy: file.fileStat}}</th>
        <th>Download</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="file in data">
        <td>{{file.filename}}</td>
        <td>{{file.fileStat |date : "dd.MM.y"}}</td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="downloadServerFile(file.filename)">download</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'sorting functionality'? Do you want your table to be ordered by date, or do you want the user to be able to customise the sorting?

Comment: user to customize sorting, just on date column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few errors in the syntax you've attempted, but you've made a good start.

The first error is that the `orderBy:` applies only to the `ng-repeat` directive.

Let's first change `<th>{{date}}</th>`.

Next, let's look at `ng-repeat`. There's two things which are of use to us. See: [OrderBy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy).

So we can tell it, using a String, which field to sort on, and with a boolean, whether to reverse the order or not. We can try something such `<tr ng-repeat="file in data | orderBy: 'fileStat': false">`.

We should also set the boolean to a variable, such that we can keep track of when the user changes it.

`<tr ng-repeat="file in data | orderBy: 'fileStat': reversed">`

Finally, let's have an `ng-click`, to allow the user to change the order. In this example, I am going to set it on the `<th>`.

`<th ng-click="reversed = !reversed">{{date}}</th>`

---

Please try this and let me know if you run into any errors.

Comment: Thanks for explanation in detail! it helped.